# PDFBox - PageDrawer draws outside the PdfPagePanel

Tags: java, pdfbox

I'm using PDFBox to show a generated pdf-file in my application.
I added the PdfPagePanel to a JScrollPane. When I make the window smaller and the scrollbars appeare, the PageDrawer draws onto the scrollbars.

This effects also occurs in the PDFReader (executable example of PDFBox).
open a pdf-file -> reduce size of window -> pdf-content get's drawn over the scrollbars

Does anybody know a way to fix this?

Enviroment:
PDFBox 1.7.1, Windows 7, Java 1.6.31

Thanks in advance,
Sascha

Answer (score 1):

I still have the same weird problem in 1.8.1.

My solution is to convert the page into a BufferedImage like this:

```
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File("C:\\Temp\\stuff.pdf"));             
    List<PDPage> allPages = document.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();

    PDPage firstPage = allPages.get(0);
    BufferedImage bi = firstPage.convertToImage();
```

Then create a normal JPanel and display the image there as you like it...

I hope that helps. Weird issue though! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The writers of PageDrawer are using setClip() without intersection with previous clip settings (e.g. from Swing). That's why they write over all other elements at the right and at the bottom of the window using PageDrawer. I wrote a Graphics delegate as a workaround. It is pretty long, but easy to use that way:

```
    PageDrawer drawer = new PageDrawer();

    try
    {
        drawer.drawPage(new StrictClip(g2D), m_page, dim);
    }
    finally
    {
        drawer.dispose();
    }
```

And now the StrictClip class itself:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Composite;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Paint;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.RenderingHints.Key;
import java.awt.Shape;
import java.awt.Stroke;
import java.awt.font.FontRenderContext;
import java.awt.font.GlyphVector;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImageOp;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.awt.image.renderable.RenderableImage;
import java.text.AttributedCharacterIterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class StrictClip extends Graphics2D
{
    protected Graphics2D m_g2D;

    public StrictClip(Graphics2D g2D)
    {
        m_g2D = g2D;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Shape s)
    {
        m_g2D.draw(s);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean drawImage(Image img, AffineTransform xform, ImageObserver obs)
    {
        return m_g2D.drawImage(img, xform, obs);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawImage(BufferedImage img, BufferedImageOp op, int x, int y)
    {
        m_g2D.drawImage(img, op, x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawRenderedImage(RenderedImage img, AffineTransform xform)
    {
        m_g2D.drawRenderedImage(img, xform);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawRenderableImage(RenderableImage img, AffineTransform xform)
    {
        m_g2D.drawRenderableImage(img, xform);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawString(String str, int x, int y)
    {
        m_g2D.drawString(str, x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawString(String str, float x, float y)
    {
        m_g2D.drawString(str, x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawString(AttributedCharacterIterator iterator, int x, int y)
    {
        m_g2D.drawString(iterator, x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawString(AttributedCharacterIterator iterator, float x, float y)
    {
        m_g2D.drawString(iterator, x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawGlyphVector(GlyphVector g, float x, float y)
    {
        m_g2D.drawGlyphVector(g, x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void fill(Shape s)
    {
        m_g2D.fill(s);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hit(Rectangle rect, Shape s, boolean onStroke)
    {
        return m_g2D.hit(rect, s, onStroke);
    }

    @Override
    public GraphicsConfiguration getDeviceConfiguration()
    {
        return m_g2D.getDeviceConfiguration();
    }

    @Override
    public void setComposite(Composite comp)
    {
        m_g2D.setComposite(comp);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPaint(Paint paint)
    {
        m_g2D.setPaint(paint);
    }

    @Override
    public void setStroke(Stroke s)
    {
        m_g2D.setStroke(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void setRenderingHint(Key hintKey, Object hintValue)
    {
        m_g2D.setRenderingHint(hintKey, hintValue);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getRenderingHint(Key hintKey)
    {
        return m_g2D.getRenderingHint(hintKey);
    }

    @Override
    public void setRenderingHints(Map<?, ?> hints)
    {
        m_g2D.setRenderingHints(hints);
    }

    @Override
    public void addRenderingHints(Map<?, ?> hints)
    {
        m_g2D.addRenderingHints(hints);
    }

    @Override
    public RenderingHints getRenderingHints()
    {
        return m_g2D.getRenderingHints();
    }

    @Override
    public void translate(int x, int y)
    {
        m_g2D.translate(x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void translate(double tx, double ty)
    {
        m_g2D.translate(tx, ty);
    }

    @Override
    public void rotate(double theta)
    {
        m_g2D.rotate(theta);
    }

    @Override
    public void rotate(double theta, double x, double y)
    {
        m_g2D.rotate(theta, x, y);
    }

    @Override
    public void scale(double sx, double sy)
    {
        m_g2D.scale(sx, sy);
    }

    @Override
    public void shear(double shx, double shy)
    {
        m_g2D.shear(shx, shy);
    }

    @Override
    public void transform(AffineTransform Tx)
    {
        m_g2D.transform(Tx);
    }

    @Override
    public void setTransform(AffineTransform Tx)
    {
        m_g2D.setTransform(Tx);
    }

    @Override
    public AffineTransform getTransform()
    {
        return m_g2D.getTransform();
    }

    @Override
    public Paint getPaint()
    {
        return m_g2D.getPaint();
    }

    @Override
    public Composite getComposite()
    {
        return m_g2D.getComposite();
    }

    @Override
    public void setBackground(Color color)
    {
        m_g2D.setBackground(color);
    }

    @Override
    public Color getBackground()
    {
        return m_g2D.getBackground();
    }

    @Override
    public Stroke getStroke()
    {
        return m_g2D.getStroke();
    }

    @Override
    public FontRenderContext getFontRenderContext()
    {
        return m_g2D.getFontRenderContext();
    }

    @Override
    public Graphics create()
    {
        return new StrictClip((StrictClip)m_g2D.create());
    }

    @Override
    public Color getColor()
    {
        return m_g2D.getColor();
    }

    @Override
    public void setColor(Color c)
    {
        m_g2D.setColor(c);
    }

    @Override
    public void setPaintMode()
    {
        m_g2D.setPaintMode();
    }

    @Override
    public void setXORMode(Color c1)
    {
        m_g2D.setXORMode(c1);
    }

    @Override
    public Font getFont()
    {
        return m_g2D.getFont();
    }

    @Override
    public void setFont(Font font)
    {
        m_g2D.setFont(font);
    }

    @Override
    public FontMetrics getFontMetrics(Font f)
    {
        return m_g2D.getFontMetrics(f);
    }

    @Override
    public Rectangle getClipBounds()
    {
        return m_g2D.getClipBounds();
    }

    @Override
    public Shape getClip()
    {
        return m_g2D.getClip();
    }

    @Override
    public void clip(Shape clip)
    {
        m_g2D.clip(clip);
    }

    @Override
    public void setClip(Shape clip)
    {
        Shape clipDev = m_g2D.getClip();
        m_g2D.setClip(null);

        if (clip != null && clipDev != null)
        {
            Rectangle rectClip = clipDev.getBounds(),
                rectClipUser = clip.getBounds();

            m_g2D.clip(rectClip.createIntersection(rectClipUser));
        }

        m_g2D.setClip(clipDev);
    }

    @Override
    public void clipRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        m_g2D.clipRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void setClip(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        setClip(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
    }

    @Override
    public void copyArea(int x, int y, int width, int height, int dx, int dy)
    {
        m_g2D.copyArea(x, y, width, height, dx, dy);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawLine(int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2)
    {
        m_g2D.drawLine(x1, y1, x2, y2);
    }

    @Override
    public void fillRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        m_g2D.fillRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void clearRect(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        m_g2D.clearRect(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawRoundRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, int arcWidth, int arcHeight)
    {
        m_g2D.drawRoundRect(x, y, width, height, arcWidth, arcHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public void fillRoundRect(int x, int y, int width, int height, int arcWidth, int arcHeight)
    {
        m_g2D.fillRoundRect(x, y, width, height, arcWidth, arcHeight);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawOval(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        m_g2D.drawOval(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void fillOval(int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        m_g2D.fillOval(x, y, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawArc(int x, int y, int width, int height, int startAngle, int arcAngle)
    {
        m_g2D.drawArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, arcAngle);
    }

    @Override
    public void fillArc(int x, int y, int width, int height, int startAngle, int arcAngle)
    {
        m_g2D.fillArc(x, y, width, height, startAngle, arcAngle);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawPolyline(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int nPoints)
    {
        m_g2D.drawPolyline(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);
    }

    @Override
    public void drawPolygon(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int nPoints)
    {
        m_g2D.drawPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);
    }

    @Override
    public void fillPolygon(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int nPoints)
    {
        m_g2D.fillPolygon(xPoints, yPoints, nPoints);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, ImageObserver observer)
    {
        return m_g2D.drawImage(img, x, y, observer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height, ImageObserver observer)
    {
        return m_g2D.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height, observer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, Color bgcolor, ImageObserver observer)
    {
        return m_g2D.drawImage(img, x, y, bgcolor, observer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean drawImage(Image img, int x, int y, int width, int height, Color bgcolor, ImageObserver observer)
    {
        return m_g2D.drawImage(img, x, y, width, height, bgcolor, observer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean drawImage(Image img, int dx1, int dy1, int dx2, int dy2, int sx1, int sy1, int sx2, int sy2, ImageObserver observer)
    {
        return m_g2D.drawImage(img, dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2, sx1, sy1, sx2, sy2, observer);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean drawImage(Image img, int dx1, int dy1, int dx2, int dy2, int sx1, int sy1, int sx2, int sy2, Color bgcolor, ImageObserver observer)
    {
        return m_g2D.drawImage(img, dx1, dy1, dx2, dy2, sx1, sy1, sx2, sy2, bgcolor, observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose()
    {
        m_g2D.dispose();
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Regards
Hans

Comment: Worked for me inside a scrollpane, thanks. It looks like you save and restore the delegate's clip shape. To me that looks equivalent to an empty override of `setClip(Shape clip)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the crop box for this.

```
page.setCropBox(new PDRectangle(panel.getWidth(), panel.getHeight()));
```

But is means you need to set the crop box everytime your panel changes size.
And i can't get it to work correctly with scrollpanes.