# How to view a PDF document using PDFBox's PDFPagePanel

Tags: java, swing, pdf

I cannot seem to figure out how to view a PDF Page using PDFBox and its PDFPagePanel component.

So it seems that using PDFBox my options are to either create a List of PDPage objects or PDDocument objects, I've gone with the PDPage list (as opposed to using `Splitter()` for PDDocument objects)

The following code creates a PDPage object named **testPage**

```
File PDF_Path = new File("C:\\PDF.PDF");
PDDocument inputPDF = PDDocument.load(PDF_Path);
List<PDPage> allPages = inputPDF.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
inputPDF.close();
PDPage testPage = (PDPage)allPages.get(0);
```

From here I would like to create a [`PDFPagePanel`](http://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/1.8.3/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfviewer/PDFPagePanel.html) and use its `setPage()` method to place the PDPage into the component.  From here I want to add the component to a JFrame.  When I do this I just see whitespace.

```
JFrame testFrame = new JFrame();
testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
PDFPagePanel pdfPanel = new PDFPagePanel();
pdfPanel.setPage(testPage);
testFrame.add(pdfPanel);
testFrame.setBounds(40, 40, pdfPanel.getWidth(), pdfPanel.getHeight());
testFrame.setVisible(true);
```

I found one 'solution' which suggest [converting the PDF to an image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16545425/679716) and displaying it as a buffered image, and while this works it doesn't seem like the correct way to do this.  Am I incorrect in trying to use PDFBox's PDFPagePanel as a means to displaying a PDF?

Comment: Did you try not closing the PDDocument so early (inputPDF.close())? I close the PDDocument when done, not when using a PDPage.

Comment: Yep I tried that too, thanks for the suggestion.  I'm not really sure why I put that line there anyways, I had it at the bottom when I copied over some code.  For now I've simply sent an email to the PDFBox mailing list and am going to look into the other options that are available. From what it looks like I shouldn't have an issue with using the other tools like iText or IcePDF as all the source code is being pushed to a public repo on GitHub, but I have never taken any sort of class dealing with licensing and open source code.

Answer (score 4):

When I comment out the inputPDF.close call, it works okay.  What if you move the close to after you are finished displaying the pdf?  Something like this...

```
testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
testFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

@Override
public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
    try {
        inputPDF.close();
        testFrame.setVisible(false);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        //  TODO: implement error handling
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}

});
```

For the record, I also implemented a PDFBox viewer as a BufferedImage wrapped in a Component wrapped in a JPanel.  Then, I was able to customize the panel with additional buttons to change pages, change documents, "zoom" or resize the image, etc.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion, this works great.  I had implemented ICEpdf but it was quite a bit of additional program than what I needed.

Comment: kevin_s. Can u post a sample code for customize panel mentioned above. I am trying to view a pdf in my java application and want to iterate through pages and zoom functions