# PFDBox: Can´t Display Page from PDF

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox

I want to display a PDF via PDFBox.

I find this working Code Example:

```
    public static void openPDF() throws IOException{
    //Locate File
    File PDF_Path = new File("C:\\Algo-Book.pdf");
    final PDDocument inputPDF = PDDocument.load(PDF_Path);
    //Get Page
    PDFPagePanel pdf = new PDFPagePanel();
    pdf.setPage((PDPage) inputPDF.getPrintable(100));
    final JFrame theFrame = new JFrame();
    theFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    theFrame.add(pdf);
    theFrame.setBounds(40, 40, pdf.getWidth(), pdf.getHeight());
    theFrame.setVisible(true);
    theFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {

    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
        try {
            inputPDF.close();
            theFrame.setVisible(false);
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            //  TODO: implement error handling
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    });
}
```

from:
 [How to view a PDF document using PDFBox's PDFPagePanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689529/how-to-view-a-pdf-document-using-pdfboxs-pdfpagepanel)

It works fine with a Pdf from google, but when I use a Algorithm PDF from   Springer which I download from the Univerity Library it Displays only the Image Part from the site like:

[image: Algo-Book]

And I get the Information:

> Aug 27, 2015 1:51:52 AM org.apache.pdfbox.util.PDFStreamEngine processOperator
>   INFORMATION: unsupported/disabled operation: ri

The Question is:
**What can I do to display the Springer PDF right ?**

Comment: Which Pdfbox version do you use?

Comment: ri = rendering intent. It just means that this operator is ignored. It may or may not be the cause of your troubles. The cause can only be told with the PDF.