# Resize a pdf using pdfbox

Tags: java, swing, pdfbox

I am attempting to view a pdf through a JFrame that contains a PDFPagePanel. While I can view the PDF, it is smaller than the actual page and therefore it appears fuzzy at best. I need the document in the full resolution and size that it is. I do NOT want to turn this into an image. I need it to stay a PDF onscreen. Here is the code I am using:

```
protected PDDocument originalDoc;
protected PDPage memDoc;
protected PDFPagePanel pdfPanel; // initialized in constructor
....

List<PDPage> memPDF = originalDoc.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
memDoc = memPDF.get(0);
pdfPanel.setPage(memDoc);
add(pdfPanel);
setBounds(1, 1, pdfPanel.getWidth(), pdfPanel.getHeight() + 51); // set JFrame to fit the size of the document + dropdown menu
pdfPanel.setVisible(true);
```

I get the PDF onscreen. It's not the correct size, though. The page itself is 8.5" x 11" and when I view it in Adobe PDF the "image" is fine and is very readable. It is very obviously not scaled correctly on the screen and I cannot find any solutions as to why? This is not the same as converting this to a BufferedImage which are the solutions I see online. I need it to stay in PDPage format and display that in the PDFPagePanel class.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689529/how-to-view-a-pdf-document-using-pdfboxs-pdfpagepanel Does not answer this question. It gave me the solution to put it on screen, but the scaling is not addressed.

Comment: Just to be sure, try the PDFToImage command line utility ( http://pdfbox.apache.org/1.8/commandline.html#pdfToImage ) to check that the PDF file is correctly converted. Note that the rendering to BufferedImage is similar to what you want, i.e. it gets a graphics device and then PageDrawer.drawPage() is called. In the (some day) upcoming 2.0 version, the PDFPagePanel class will be removed soon. Instead, we render to BufferedImage and display that one into a JLabel with label.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image)); .