# How to view a PDF document using PDFBox v2

Tags: java, swing, pdf, pdfbox

I found some topics about [how to view a PDF Page using PDFBox and its PDFPagePanel Component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21689529/how-to-view-a-pdf-document-using-pdfboxs-pdfpagepanel) but the `PDFPagePanel` seems to be deprecated and removed from `PDFBox` 2.* since it caused too many problems.

How can I do this without the mentioned Component?

I want to get the view of each PDF page and display it in my own application in a `JFrame`.

Comment: You can still convert the PDF page to an image and display it using `JLabel`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I should have been more precise: I want to work with the text on the page to translate it when hovering over a sentence.

Comment: Whoa - that would be a huge project. The PDFPagePanel component can't do that either. Anyway, to display rendered pages, have a look at the PDFDebugger sources and at the example in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PDFBOX-3359 . To identify the borders of texts, have a look at the DrawPrintTextLocations.java example in the source code download.